# Excel Vba how to find row's minimum value in for loop

Tags: excel, vba, dijkstra

I am using dijkstra algorithm for VRP , so it works like this
i am giving an random input between node numbers (1,2,3,..) and after that input it takes it as i and starting to searching for minimum value in i. row and finding the minimum value at j. column so next step j becomes my next row and i am trying to iterate as like that
so i need to find minimum value of row's in for loop i tried to giving

```
application.worksheet.function.min(range) 

For i = Sheets("sayfa1").Cells(15, 1) To Sheets("sayfa1").Cells(15, 1) + 1
For j = i + 1 To 11
    if cell(i,j) = application.WorksheetFunction.Min(range of row) then
         cell.clearcontents
    end if
   i = j 
nextj
```

but range always changing by row so it doesn't work

Comment: Does this code actually run?

Comment: not actually it was a pseudo code , i just struggled at this spot and wanted to ask

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear to me what you need to determine exactly. As far as I have understood, I have quickly written a macro for your question. Hope it solves your problem or at least helps you to get to the solution. You could try something like this:

```
Sub Min_values_loop()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim FirstCol As Long, LastCol As Long, FirstRow As Long, LastRow, MinValue As Long

'set sheet name
Set ws1 = Worksheets("sayfa1")

'set your frist and last column and row numbers here
FirstCol = 1
LastCol = 3
FirstRow = 1
LastRow = 10

'loop through columns
For i = FirstCol To LastCol
    MinValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws1.Range(Cells(FirstRow, i), Cells(LastRow, i)))
    MsgBox "The minimum value in the range is " & MinValue
Next i

End Sub
```

You can change the first and last row number or the column numbers as per your requirement.

Comment: thank you for helping but it isn't what i searched for can you tell me where should i explain more , my main thing is i will search minimum values of the rows' but selected rows always be in changing , loop will determine the rows like if my first minimum value at (1,7) then i will clear cell and my next row will be 7